# Create Active Directory schema into OpenLDAP

Tags: active-directory, schema, openldap

I need to store Active Directory Data into OpenLDAP and for that I want to create the Active Directory schema into OpenLDAP. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Active Directory schema file was for some time a part of the OpenLDAP sources tarball. Now, it's no longer here and I could not find it in the CSV head. However, the microsoft.schema file is included in many Linux distos and also it's [pretty easy to find it](http://www.google.com/search?q=microsoft.schema+openldap) standalone.